# How to print values of an array in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, 64-bit

I'm trying to print the third value of my array but I cant figure out how to print the value and not some crazy random number

I can print numbers 0-9 with just the normal technique but printing bigger numbers does not work. When i was debugging it showed that in `printNumber` the `eax` register was the memory address of numbers when it should have been the value

here's the code:

```
section .data
    numbers db 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70

section .text
    global _start

    _start:
        
        mov r8, numbers + 2

        printNumber [r8]        ; prints 117835012
        printNumber 3000        ; prints 3000
```

printNumber macro:

```
section .bss
    digit resb 0

%macro printNumber 1
    mov eax, %1

    %%printInt:
        mov rcx, digit      ;set rcx to digit memory address
        mov rbx, 10         ; moving a newline into rbx
        mov [rcx], rbx      ; setting digit to rbx
        inc rcx             ; increment rcx position by one byte

    %%storeLoop:
        xor rdx, rdx        ; zero out rdx
        mov rbx, 10         
        div rbx             ; rax / rbx (10)

                            ; rdx holds the remainder of the divison
        add rdx, 48         ; add 48 to rdx to make in ascii character
                            
        mov [rcx], dl       ; get the character part of rdx
        inc rcx             ; increment digit position again

        cmp rax, 0
        jnz %%storeLoop       ; continue looping until rax is 0

    %%printLoop:
        push rcx

        ;perform sys write
        mov rax, SYSWRITE
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, rcx
        mov rdx, 1
        syscall

        pop rcx
        dec rcx
        cmp rcx, digit      ; first byte of digit (10)
        jge %%printLoop

%endmacro
```

Comment: After you have loaded `eax` with `[r8]` (in the first line of your macro), you actually loaded `rax` with the number `0x0000000028323C46`.  This is not the value that should be divided by ten in `%%storeLoop`.  You should also reserve more bytes than 0 for `digit`.

Comment: @vitsoft The endianess of the number is wrong! 0x0000000028323C46 should be 0x00000000463C3228.

Comment: @SepRoland Mea culpa, thanks, I noticed but later than 5 min. Both numbers are rubish anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Why did you not already improve your code regarding the post-increment vs pre-decrement issue for which I provided an answer in your previous question
[Assembly prints character before a big number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72473527/assembly-prints-character-before-a-big-number/72474230#72474230) ?

The invokation `printNumber [r8]` leads to the instruction `mov eax, [r8]` for the macro line that reads `mov eax, %1`. This `mov` instruction will load a **dword** from memory, and because your *numbers* array is composed of **byte**-sized elements, you will have combined 4 of these into one big number: `RAX = 0x00000000463C3228`.

### Solution 1 is to define the array holding dwords, but it requires changing the offset that is used to address the 3rd element.

```
section .data
    numbers dd 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70

section .text
    global _start

    _start:
        
        mov r8, numbers + 8
        printNumber [r8]          ; -> mov eax, [r8]
```

### Solution 2 is to keep the array byte-sized, but make sure to feed a dword value to the macro

```
section .data
    numbers db 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70

section .text
    global _start

    _start:
        
        movzx r8d, byte [numbers + 2]
        printNumber r8d           ; -> mov eax, r8d
```